# Getting exceptions in Unity3d with EasyRoads3D, when attempting to create roads

Tags: unity, exceptions

After importing EasyRoads3D version 3.2.2f2 into Unity 2021.3.20f1, and trying to create a simple road, I get a lot of exceptions:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
EasyRoads3Dv3Editor.ODOOCODCQO.OCCOCQDOOD (EasyRoads3Dv3.ERModularBase scr) (at :0)
EasyRoads3Dv3Editor.ODDQDODCCC.OnEnable () (at :0)
UnityEditor.PrefabUtility:CreateEmptyPrefab(String)
EasyRoads3Dv3Editor.OODCCDOQQQ:OODDDDODOC()
EasyRoads3Dv3Editor.ODDQDODCCC:OnEnable()

MissingMethodException: Method not found: UnityEngine.Vector3 UnityEditor.Handles.FreeMoveHandle(UnityEngine.Vector3,single,UnityEngine.Vector3,UnityEditor.Handles/CapFunction)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at :0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at :0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at :0)
UnityEditor.SceneView.CallOnSceneGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:3641)
UnityEditor.SceneView.HandleSelectionAndOnSceneGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2740)
UnityEditor.SceneView.DoOnGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2411)
UnityEditor.SceneView.OnSceneGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2255)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event evt, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 parentTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Boolean isComputingLayout, UnityEngine.Rect layoutSize, System.Action onGUIHandler, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/IMGUIContainer.cs:351)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

GUI Error: You are pushing more GUIClips than you are popping. Make sure they are balanced.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

MissingMethodException: Method not found: UnityEngine.Vector3 UnityEditor.Handles.FreeMoveHandle(UnityEngine.Vector3,single,UnityEngine.Vector3,UnityEditor.Handles/CapFunction)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at :0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at :0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at :0)
UnityEditor.SceneView.CallOnSceneGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:3641)
UnityEditor.SceneView.HandleSelectionAndOnSceneGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2740)
UnityEditor.SceneView.DoOnGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2411)
UnityEditor.SceneView.OnSceneGUI () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2255)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event evt, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 parentTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Boolean isComputingLayout, UnityEngine.Rect layoutSize, System.Action onGUIHandler, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/IMGUIContainer.cs:372)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event e, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 worldTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Action onGUIHandler, System.Boolean canAffectFocus) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/IMGUIContainer.cs:693)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoIMGUIRepaint () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/IMGUIContainer.cs:553)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIR.RenderChainCommand.ExecuteNonDrawMesh (UnityEngine.UIElements.UIR.DrawParams drawParams, System.Single pixelsPerPoint, System.Exception& immediateException) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Renderer/UIRenderer/UIRenderers.cs:129)
Rethrow as ImmediateModeException
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIR.RenderChain.Render () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Renderer/UIRRenderChain.cs:513)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIRRepaintUpdater.Update () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Renderer/UIRRepaintUpdater.cs:79)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeUpdater.UpdateVisualTreePhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeUpdatePhase phase) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/VisualTreeUpdater.cs:155)
UnityEngine.UIElements.Panel.UpdateForRepaint () (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Panel.cs:994)
UnityEngine.UIElements.Panel.Repaint (UnityEngine.Event e) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Panel.cs:1046)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel panel) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/UIElementsUtility.cs:448)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& eventHandled) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/UIElementsUtility.cs:211)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/UIElementsUtility.cs:74)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration+<>c.b__1_2 (System.Int32 i, System.IntPtr ptr) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/UIElementsUtility.cs:28)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& result) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

The last couple of exceptions tend to come over and over again, as long as I have the `Road Network` object selected in the hierarchy.

Is this a bug in Unity? In EasyRoads3D? Or in my setup or because I'm using Linux on an unsupported system (Ubuntu 22.10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I downloaded EasyRoads3D with a different version of Unity (IIRC 2022.2.something), and this somehow created a mismatch when importing it into a different version.

The solution was to remove the cached downloaded EasyRoads3D assets (Linux command shown):

```
$ rm -rf ~/.local/share/unity3d/Asset Store-5.x/AndaSoft
```

And then re-download it using the Unity version I want to use them in.

The cache location is found in [this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetStorePackages.html#asset-location).

For form information about removing downloaded and cached asset files, there's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-del-pkg-as-cache.html) for that as well.